# Label a point when the x-axis is time/date

Tags: plot, gnuplot

my data.dat looks like this

```
2018-01-15, 3268
2018-02-07, 3783
2018-02-08, 7569
```

And the relevant parts of my plot.plt looks like this

```
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
set xdata time
set format x "%b/%d"
```

What I am trying to do is plot the data and put a label (with the text "label") on a point thats 2018-02-28 on the x-axis and 5000 on the y-axis, but I'm not getting the following lines to work.

```
plot "data.dat" using 1:2 w lines ls 1
set label 1 at  2018-02-08, 5000 'label' center rotate by 45 front
```

The error I get is shown on the following line is pointing a ^ on the date-part of the "set label"

```
"plot.plt", line 39: unexpected or unrecognized token
```

Any idea how I can place this label?

Comment: Enclose 2018-02-08 in quotes.

Comment: That did fix the error, but the label is not appearing. I tried to place it at an earlier date, and at different y-values in case it was rendered out of the frame.

Comment: It started working after moving the line with "set label" before the line with "plot".

Comment: ah, that worked. I did actually try that first, but somehow it didnt take. You should reply that as an answer and ill mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was as in the comments above:

1. Enclose the date in quotes `"2018-02-08"`
2. Move the `set label 1 at  "2018-02-08" ...` before the `plot "data.dat" ...`